# Convertit fecha "YYYY-MM-DD" A "DD-MM-YYYY"

Tags: javascript

Tengo un arreglo de fechas de la siguiente forma:

```
[   "2022-01-03",
    "2022-01-04",
    "2022-01-05",
    "2022-01-06",
    "2022-01-07",
    "2022-01-08",
    "2022-01-10",
    "2022-01-11",
    "2022-01-12",
    "2022-01-13",
    "2022-01-14",
    "2022-01-15",
    "2022-01-17",
    "2022-01-18",
    "2022-01-19",
    "2022-01-20",
    "2022-01-21",
    "2022-01-22",
    "2022-01-24",
    "2022-01-25",
    "2022-01-26",
    "2022-01-27",
    "2022-01-28"]
```

Necesito convertir todas esas fechas a DD-MM-YYY. Sería DÍA/MES/AÑO.
Lo intenté con moment js de la siguiente forma:

```
moment(MyArray)).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Pero no me funciona. Solamente me lo convierte si mando una fecha sola y necesito transformar todas las del array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba de la siguiente forma:

```
const newFormat = MyArray.map(dia => dia.split('-').reverse().join('/'));
```

Utilizamos el método split para dividir el string a partir del carácter '-' y obtener un array de strings, luego utilizamos el método reverse para invertir el orden del array y por ultimo unimos todo con el método join concatenando el carácter '/'

Answer (score 0):

esto debería funcionar perfectamente:

```
    let fechas = ["2022-01-03",
    "2022-01-04",
    "2022-01-05",
    "2022-01-06",
    "2022-01-07",
    "2022-01-08",
    "2022-01-10",
    "2022-01-11",
    "2022-01-12",
    "2022-01-13",
    "2022-01-14",
    "2022-01-15",
    "2022-01-17",
    "2022-01-18",
    "2022-01-19",
    "2022-01-20",
    "2022-01-21",
    "2022-01-22",
    "2022-01-24",
    "2022-01-25",
    "2022-01-26",
    "2022-01-27",
    "2022-01-28"];

    fechas = fechas.map( item => moment( item ).format( "DD-MM-YYYY" ));
    console.log( fechas );
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias me funcionó! Pero al momento de enviar mis datos a la tabla lo hago de la siguiente forma:     Object.keys(allDataForChart)
        .map(arreglo =>{
            tableOfSalesDate.row.add({ 'Día': arreglo, 'Ventas': allDataForChart[arreglo]}).draw(false)
        })

Comment: Como puedo mandar la fecha ya formateada dentro del Object.Keys? O formatearla dentro

Comment: Quiero pensar que "arreglo" es cada fecha y es lo que agregas en la propiedad "Día", si ese es el caso podrías asignarlo asi: Object.keys(allDataForChart).map( arreglo => {
            let nuevaFecha = moment( arreglo ).format( "DD-MM-YYYY" )
            tableOfSalesDate.row.add({ 
                'Día': nuevaFecha, 
                'Ventas': allDataForChart[nuevaFecha]
            }).draw(false) 
        });